# Call to undefined method stdClass::checkSubcategory()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to make a dynamic Menu where in menu section i want to show a category and if the category has any subcategory I wanted to show it under it..

I have read the following method on my category model

```
public static function checkSubcategory($id){
        $category = Category::find($id);
        $id = $category->id;
        $subcategories = \DB::table ('subcategories')
                    ->join('categories_subcategories','subcategories.id','=','categories_subcategories.subcategory_id')
                    ->join('categories','categories_subcategories.category_id','=','categories.id')
                    ->where('categories.id','=',$id)
                    ->select('subcategories.name')
                    ->get();    
         return $subcategories;
    }
```

And here is the View

```
@foreach($categories as $row)
                @if($row->checkSubcategory($row->id))       
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        {{$row->name}}
                    </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                    @foreach($row->checkSubcategory($row->id) as $sub)
                    <a href="{{asset('subcategories/product/'.$sub->name)}}">{{$sub->name}}</a>
                    @endforeach 
                    </li>                                               
                </ul>
                </li>
                    @else 
                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">{{$row->name}}</a></li>
                    @endif      
                @endforeach
```

But the problem is when ever i tried to load the view i see the following Error

> ```
> ErrorException in efd7d9fe55aa0c18c60d0a857a8a44ed1725a390.php line 213:
> Call to undefined method stdClass::checkSubcategory()
> ```

What could be reason for the error..any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1):

The object you are using of type stdClass and therefore cannot get access to the function you define in your controller model. A likely cause is that you are getting your categories using `DB`. It gives you an array with objects of type stdClass. What you need is objects of type `Category`. Therefore you should get your categories using the Category model

```
//change
$categories = DB::table('categories')->get();
//to
$categories = Category::get();
```

Also, you defined it as a static function

```
public static function checkSubcategory($id)
```

Means you cannot call it with an object

```
$row->checkSubcategory($row->id)
```

Remove `static` keyword from the function definition.

Furthermore, you could refactor your function. Instead of passing it the id, just get the id with `$this->id`.

```
public function checkSubcategory(){
    return \DB::table ('subcategories')
                ->join('categories_subcategories','subcategories.id','=','categories_subcategories.subcategory_id')
                ->join('categories','categories_subcategories.category_id','=','categories.id')
                ->where('categories.id','=', $this->id)
                ->select('subcategories.name')
                ->get();    
}
```

You could even dive deeper and make your code nicer with relationships.

```
public function subcategories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(SubCategory::class, 'categories_subcategories', 'category_id', 'subcategory_id');
    //Why do you have a many to many relationships between categories and subcategories ?
}
```

Your checkSubcategory would then becomes

```
public function checkSucategory() {
    return $this->subcategories()->count();
}
```

Comment: even though i have remove the static keyword..I got the same Error .. 
why many to many relation? suppose wordpress has blog subcategory, lifestyle same as Html has also blog subcategory , business template like that ..

Comment: Show me how you get your categories from the controller. The $categories you use in the `foreach($categories as $row)`

Comment: Try with `categories = Category::get()`; And make sure that function is defined exactly in the Category model.

Comment: No, Same Error I'm getting ..You are talking about `checkSubcategory` function right?

Comment: Can you update your question and put your controller in it? please.

Comment: I put `$categories = Category::get();
        View::share('categories', $categories);` in AppServiceProvider boot method ..
i tried to make it viewable in other page also ..that's why

Comment: I have already defined the many to many relationship.so instead of calling the method I should access the data ase `$row->subcategories->name` but i got error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139673/discussion-between-eddythedove-and-user57).